# Buffalo Link Station

Tags: networking, buffalo

I have a buffalo link station LS 500 GL and it's in the network so around 6 of us access it as a common storage. I would like to know if this link station can be accessed from outside this network via web browser. It wil be great if there is an option as it will help if someone is out of town and if they want to access it. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I din't see the exact model you describe but most current LinkStations support remote access.  Naturally, the network border/gateway router would need tro be configured to allow such access.  Comparison of models here with full part numbers and features. [LinkStation](http://buffalotech.com/comparison-charts/network-storage/home-and-small-office/)

Comment: thanks that helps. I don't think the model i have has this web access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN) connection, you can attach to your network remotely and access the file share that way.  Keep in mind that it will be much slower, depending on the internet connections at your site and the remote user's site.  Sometimes as much as 100 times slower...

Comment: thanks but i think i explored this option and dint like it much